# My Drools Decision Table is giving wrong output

Tags: java, drools

Facing an issue while fetching output from Drools Decision Table.
PFB attached screen shot of Decision Table.

In DT, some cells in CONDITION column are blank and some aren't. TASK NAME, COUNTRY column have multiple cells with same value.

When I compile this, in DRL file I can see rule is created with cells having values, and blank cells are ignored.

But, my requirement is to include those blank and non-blank cells in rule.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Decision table]

With current implementation of DT, it's giving wrong output:

- If I use `session.fireAllRules(1);` it gives 1st row output.
- If I use `session.fireAllRules();`  it gives 6th row output.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question -- what is going on, and how to do what you want it to. I'll address them in order.

---

#### What's going on

Your final observations about `fireAllRules` are explaining what's going on.

If you pass a number to `fireAllRules`, it will stop after firing that many rules. If you don't give it a number, it will evaluate all rules.

The reason you're getting different results is because your input is such that you're triggering multiple rules.

Here's an example. If you `fireAllRules()` with this input:

```
Discount{
  taskName: "Discount",
  country: "IN",
  oldProductGroup: "Cadbury",
  oldProductType: "New"
)
```

You will trigger rule 1 and the last one in the screenshot (looks like rule 8).

It triggers rule 1, because that rule will trigger for all Discount inputs with task name "Discount" and country "IN". It has no other requirements.

It triggers rule 8, because it meets the task name, country, old product group, and old product type conditions.

(The other rules in between might fire too -- I didn't show what the other fields are set to. You can actually get most of your tables to trigger if you set oldSupplier = "ABC" and urgency = "High".)

What will actually be returned by `fireAllRules` will be the *last* rule to match.

---

#### Doing what you want it to

You say your requirements are to "include the blank cells in the rule". Drools doesn't do that. What you need to do is design your rules so that those blank cells are not actually blank but interpreted correctly. In your example, how are we supposed to differentiate the meaning of a blank between "any value can be in this slot" versus "this slot must not have a value (null)" versus "this slot must be a blank string"? Drools interprets an empty cell as there being no condition relating to that field, so it basically ignores that field or condition.

If you reorder your rules to have the most-specific rules first, you might be able to get away with just calling `fireAllRules(1)` which will return after the first match. This will likely get a bit hairy if you have lots of empty conditions.

Otherwise, you can add null check columns. Using 'dummy' column as an example:

```
| CONDITION   | CONDITION     |
| mappingObject: Discount     |
| dummy == $1 | dummy == null |
| DUMMY       | DUMMY NOT SET |
| foo         |               |
|             | X             |
```

First column "DUMMY" works like your current spreadsheet column. Populate it if you want to match some value in this field.

Second column "DUMMY NOT SET" works like your requirements want -- it explicitly checks that the value is *not set*. You just need to stick a value in this field (doesn't matter what the value is) to get the condition to be added to the rule.

So for every one of your columns, add a second 'NOT SET' column, and then the fields you want to additionally do a null check for in the rule you need to populate those columns.

It's gross. But Drools doesn't work like this.

Comment: the legacy decision table format of Drools, I agree, at times might require a bit of gross-y solution like this one :)

Comment: Hi @tarilabs, Thanks for the answer. But, I didn't understand DUMMY NOT SET properly. Let's say, if I have 15 CONDITION columns, then I'll need total 30 CONDITION columns, one as COUNTRY(e.g.) and other as COUNTRY NOT SET ?  

And I tried null == "$param" || "$param".isEmpty() ||  "$param".trim().isEmpty() || mappingObject.country == "$param" but this didn't work.